# CSS - how to make the iframe inside the div center aligned and the main div also center?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

How to make the iframe inside this div center? right now its showing to the left + the main div is also showing to the left instead of center of the browser.

```
#video_window { 
/*  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;*/

  width: 850px;
  height: 650px;
  position: fixed; top:0px; left:0px;
  background-color: black;

  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding:1px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

#video_window .video_frame {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
/*  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;*/
/*  border: 1px solid #009;  */
}

</style>


<!-- a video screen should be center -->
<div id="video_window" class="video_window" style="
     ">
      <iframe id="video_one" class="video_frame" style="z-index: 0;" width="800" height="600" 
            src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/lVjdlpS_Vzw?rel=0" 
            frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    <iframe id="video_two"  class="video_frame" style="z-index: 0;" width="800" height="600" 
            src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/lVjdlpS_Vzw?rel=0" 
            frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

On the `.video_frame`

Comment: tried but not working still same all showing in left.